# Simplification in operator-sum representation (Nielsen and Chuang)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer, density-operator

First remark: there is a similar question: [Operator-sum representation of a quantum operation with different input and output spaces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388671/operator-sum-representation-of-a-quantum-operation-with-different-input-and-outp) which helped more generally, but I am still stuck on a part unasked there.

Specifically, in chapter eight of Mike & Ike, equation 8.9 shows the quantum operation on a state $\rho$ interacting with an environment originally in state $\vert e_0 \rangle \langle e_0\vert$ evolves unitarily in time via  $U \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B)$ where the quantum state and environment live in $\mathcal{H}_A, \mathcal{H}_B$ respectively.

$$\varepsilon(\rho) = \sum_k \langle e_k\rvert U [\rho \otimes \lvert e_0 \rangle \langle e_0 \rvert]U^\dagger \lvert e_k \rangle = \sum_k E_k \rho E_k^\dagger $$

where $E_k = \langle e_k \vert U \vert e_0 \rangle$. We trace out the environment system (i.e. $\vert e_k\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_B$).

My question: **How can we manipulate the tensor product in order to identify $E_k$ as given?**

Do we have to expand state $\rho$ for the manipulation? How can I see the tensor product operation here more clearly?

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276053/trouble-with-operator-sum-representation-of-a-quantum-operation?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: see also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4981/55 and links therein